# How to extract the required element using find_all()

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to extract the authors' names in the amazon page. The problem is, there are so many tags with same class and there are no other attributes to identify the exact element. Now i want to extract the author name. It is present in the second span tag.

```html
<div class="a-row a-spacing-none">
<span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary">by </span>
<span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary"><a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/Arthur-Conan-Doyle/e/B000AQ43GQ/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_2?qid=1510823399&amp;sr=8-2">Arthur Conan Doyle</a></span></div>
```

As we can, there is a same class for both span tags. I want the second span tag.And more over, the a tag is not present in all blocks. So i have to use only span tag to extract the author name. How could i get the author name?

I am using BeautifulSoup and selenium.My code is:

```
        soup=BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source,"html.parser")
    titles=soup.find_all("h2",{"class":"a-size-medium s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal"})
    authors=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"a-size-small a-color-secondary"})
    for value in range(len(titles)):
        d={}
        d["Title"]=titles[value].text
        d["Author"]=authors[value+2].text
        title.append(d)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find the above "div" element for that "span". then extract the entire text of the div tag.As u observe, there will be a "by" substring in every block of code. Use it to split the text and copy it to the d["Author"] part. If "by" is not present, check before copying it to dictionary using if condition. If u copy directly, then u may get Array out of Bound exception. So use if.

Here is the code:

```
temp = authors[value].text
temp1 = temp.split("by")
#print(temp[1])
if temp1[0]!=temp:
    d["Author"] = temp1[1]
else:
    d["Author"] = "None"
```